# How to filter string for unwanted characters using regex?

Tags: java, regex

Basically , I am wondering if there is a handy class or method to filter a String for unwanted characters. The output of the method should be the 'cleaned' String. Ie:

```
String dirtyString = "This contains spaces which are not allowed"

String result = cleaner.getCleanedString(dirtyString);
```

Expecting result would be:

```
"Thiscontainsspaceswhicharenotallowed"
```

A better example:

```
String reallyDirty = " this*is#a*&very_dirty&String"

String result = cleaner.getCleanedString(dirtyString);
```

I expect the result to be:

```
"thisisaverydirtyString"
```

Because, i let the cleaner know that ' ', '*', '#', '&' and '_' are dirty characters. I can solve it by using a white/black list array of chars. But I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

I was wondering if there is already such a thing that can 'clean' strings using a regex. Instead of writing this myself.

Addition:
If you think cleaning a String could be done differently/better then I'm all ears as well of course

Another addition:
- It is not only for spaces, but for any kind of character.

Comment: So really unwanted characters means anything that is not a a-z or 0-9?  I updated my answer, but it is still unclear what is a dirty character and what is a clean one.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Edited based on your update:

```
dirtyString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]","")
```

Comment: @Tim, the definition of a clean vs dirty character from Stefan has been a little unclear.  Originally it was just spaces.

Comment: Clean letters are just a-z and A-Z , no special chars. Looks like the replaceAll Will be what I need

Comment: --SOLVED, silly fail--
the method doesn't modify the String,returns the modified one

String temp2 = tempString.replaceAll(",",".");

Answer (score 14):

If you're using [guava](https://github.com/google/guava) on your project (and if you're not, I believe you should consider it), the [CharMatcher](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.guava/guava/26.0-jre/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) class handles this very nicely:

Your first example might be:

```
result = CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.removeFrom(dirtyString);
```

while your second might be:

```
result = CharMatcher.anyOf(" *#&").removeFrom(dirtyString);
// or alternatively
result = CharMatcher.noneOf(" *#&").retainFrom(dirtyString);
```

or if you want to be more flexible with whitespace (tabs etc), you can combine them rather than writing your own:

```
CharMatcher illegal = CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.or(CharMatcher.anyOf("*#&"));
result = illegal.removeFrom(dirtyString);
```

or you might instead specify legal characters, which depending on your requirements might be:

```
CharMatcher legal = CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER; // based on Unicode char class
CharMatcher legal = CharMatcher.ASCII.and(CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER); // only letters which are also ASCII, as your examples
CharMatcher legal = CharMatcher.inRange('a', 'z'); // lowercase only
CharMatcher legal = CharMatcher.inRange('a', 'z').or(CharMatcher.inRange('A', 'Z')); // either case
```

followed by `retainFrom(dirtyString)` as above.

Very nice, powerful API.

Comment: Links broken :(

Answer (score 9):

Use [`replaceAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 6):

This will do it:

```
String dirtyString = "This contains spaces which are not allowed";
String result = dirtyString.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

and works by replacing all whitespace with 'nothing'.

Answer (score 6):

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("\\P{L}+", "");
```

will replace any non-letter characters with nothing.

Comment: Clever answer using the regex pattern for the whole category of Unicode letters.

Answer (score 0):

I also prefer the whitelisting-approach. You'll never know what comes around. There seem to be more encodings in than characters. This way you can control it all:

```
public String convert(String s) {
  s = StringUtils.removePattern(s, "[^A-Za-zäöüÄÖÜß?!$,. 0-9\\-\\+\\*\\?=&%\\$§\"\\!\\^#:;,_²³°\\[\\]\\{\\}<>\\|~]'`'");
  return s.trim();
}
```

This contains all german umlauts and french accents and ... you know - just look at your keyboard. I think I picked them all.
Feel free to omit special chars like < > to prevent code-injection...

Answer (score 0):

## Filter code points

Regex is not the only avenue to your goal. You can get the [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer number for each character in your string, then filter out those not considered a letter in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

The `String#codePoints` method returns an `IntStream`, a stream of `int` primitive values, one per character.

The `Character` class can tell us if the character assigned to each of those code point numbers in Unicode is considered a letter, as opposed to [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character), digits, punctuation, and so on.

Those code points passing our test are converted back to a `String` by way of the `StringBuilder` class.

```
String input = " this*is#a*&very_dirty&String" ; 
String onlyLetters = 
        input 
        .codePoints()
        .filter(
            codePoint -> Character.isLetter( codePoint ) 
        )
        .collect(               
            StringBuilder :: new ,        
            StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint , 
            StringBuilder :: append    
        )        
        .toString() 
;
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/MVa1tV).

> thisisaverydirtyString