# strip/remove specific character from string in JAVA

Tags: java, string, character, removeall

i have a string variable say 'result'. The value of this string should contain only alphabets, numerics, dot, space, hyphen and underscore. The regular expression i arrived at is '^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-z ._-]'.

How can i use this regular expression on the string variable? Please help me.

Any other suggesstion is also welcome. Basically i need to have only alpha-numeric, dot,space, hyphen, underscore in the string value.

Please help.

**Part of answer:**
i am able to partly achieve the behavior using

```
string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

But i could not add dot, space, hyphen, underscore to the above validation. The above validation removes all the characters expect alpha-numeric characters. But i need dot, space, hyphen, underscore are also not to be replaced/removed from the orginal String.

Any ideas please??

Comment: The answer is here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945695/how-to-filter-string-for-unwanted-characters-using-regex][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945695/how-to-filter-string-for-unwanted-characters-using-regex

Answer (score 2):

Just use `.replaceAll("[aeiou]","")` This will work.

Comment: This will remove the wovels alone.. i need to remove characters other than alphabets, numerics, hyphen, dot , space and underscore

Comment: try using [a-zA-Z0-9_@!}{$|#^\*\\[\\]:/.=\\\\? ]

Answer (score 1):

Just use `yourstring.split()` method and split the string from where you want to remove the symbol and then again append the string.

Have fun...

Answer (score 1):

Modify the regexp you have `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` to match those characters you want:

```
string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\._-]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily do it by storing that string in any variable after that use StringBuilder object and append the character or symbol you want to add according to their place.

```
yourString.setText(new StringBuilder().append("character or symbol").append(anystring)
                .append(":"));
```

You can easily do from above code.

Answer (score 0):

String x = "a c d"
you want to replace all the spaces by (-)
x = x.replace(" ", "-");

Comment: Not exactly, in the question it is said that "string should contain only alphabets, numerics, dot, **space**, hyphen and underscore"