# Wildcards in Java String creation

Tags: java, string, wildcard

Am analyzing user input strings. I only want the strings that contains any combination of the digits 1,2,3 and the letters a, b and c. How can I set up a wildcard with these criteria in order to accept or reject the strings?

I want to reject all characters except the ones I need.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Assuming a user enters `abc123`, **how** do you like to prevent the user from pressing a `4`? Are you close to the physical body of the user and are experienced in karate?

Comment: The requirement is unclear - do you want to _match_ the input (i.e. every input with other characters is invalid) or do you want to _filter_ (i.e. remove all other characters from the input)?

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945695/how-to-filter-string-for-unwanted-characters-using-regex) will allow you to filter out unwanted characters

Comment: What I want is something like this:  String userinput = "whatever"  if(userinput.contains("Any character I don't need) programs stops else program goes on @Andreas_D

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should take a look at this : [Java regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

E.g. :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-c1-3]*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("aaaaab");
boolean b = m.matches();
```