# Java String Filter out unwanted characters

Tags: java, regex, string, char, special-characters

I have string like this:

```
−+-~*/@$^#¨%={}[häagen-dazs;:] a (le & co') jsou "výborné" <značky>?!.
```

And I want to end up with this:

```
häagen-dazs a le & co jsou výborné značky.
```

In comparison to [How to filter string for unwanted characters using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945695/how-to-filter-string-for-unwanted-characters-using-regex) I want to keep accent (diacritics) in the string.

I use following replaceAll:

```
str.replaceAll("[¨%=;\\:\\(\\)\\$\\[\\]\\{\\}\\<\\>\\+\\*\\−\\@\\#\\~\\?\\!\\^\\'\\\"\\|\\/]", "");
```

- Is this correct approach?
- Is there a more simple way how to keep only alphanumeric characters (as well as with accent), spaces, and & . - symbols?

Comment: @Tushar That regex would remove diacritic letters.

Comment: Try `replaceAll("(?U)[^\\p{L}\\p{N}\\s&.-]", "") `

Comment: Here is a [demo](http://rextester.com/TQFI40953) using Wiktor's comment.

Comment: With `CharMatcher.javaLetterOrDigit().or(CharMatcher.anyOf(" &-.")).retainFrom(yourInput)` you end up with `-häagen-dazs a le & co jsou výborné značky.` (`CharMatcher` from guava, NB: there's a space before &)

Comment: @Michal: But it is overkill to match each char against a regex. If that solution works, you really need just `s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z& _.ýčéèêàâùû-]", "")`. What about uppercase `ýčéèêàâùû`? I think you should not accept that answer, I'll post mine.

Comment: *I think you should not accept that answer* ?! Really?!! **I think** it's up to the OP to choose what really suits his case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all the input `String` characters and test each one if it matches your wanted Regex keep it, use this Regex `[a-zA-Z& \\-_\\.ýčéèêàâùû]` to test upon each character individually.

This is the code you need:

```
    String input = "−+-~*/@$^#¨%={}[häagen-dazs;:] a (le & co') jsou výborné <značky>?!";
    StringBuffer sb =  new StringBuffer();
    for(char c : input.toCharArray()){
       if((Character.toString(c).toLowerCase()).matches("[a-zA-Z& \\-_\\.ýčéèêàâùû]")){
           sb.append(c);
       }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**Demo:**

And here's [a working **Demo**](http://rextester.com/PCEABC96684) that uses this code and gives the following output:

```
-hagen-dazs. a le & co jsou výborné značky
```

**Note:**

- It uses `input.toCharArray()` to get an array of `char`s and loop over it.
- It uses `(Character.toString(c).toLowerCase()).matches("[a-zA-Z& \\-_\\.ýčéèêàâùû]")` to test if the iterated `char` matches the allowed characters Regex.
- It uses a `StringBuffer` to construct a new `String` with only the
  allowed characters.

Comment: This is the best solution for me. For anybody else who wants to support full czech / slovak / german languages, use: (Character.toString(c).toLowerCase()).matches("[a-z& \\-_\\.äáàâčďéèêěíľňóöřšťùûúůüýž]")

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
String res = input.replaceAll("(?U)[^\\p{L}\\p{N}\\s&.-]+", "");
```

Note that the regex matches any character other than  (because `[^...]` is a negated character class), one or more times (due to the `+`  quantifier):

- `\p{L}` - any Unicode letter
- `\p{N}` - any Unicode digit
- `\s` - any Unicode whitespace (`\s` becomes Unicode aware due to the `(?U)` inline `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` modifier version)
- `&`  - a literal `&`
- `.` - a literal `.`
- `-` - a literal hyphen (as it is placed at the end of the character class

[Java demo](http://rextester.com/OPAM31575):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String input = "−+-~*/@$^#¨%={}[häagen-dazs;:] a (le & co') jsou výborné <značky>?!";
        input = input.replaceAll("(?U)[^\\p{L}\\p{N}\\s&.-]+", "");
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

Output: `-häagen-dazs a le & co jsou výborné značky`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
str.replaceAll("[\\\/\.\:\%\!\[\]\(\)\{\}\?\^\*\+\"\'#@$;¨=&<>-~−]", "");
```

Your regex had something wrong with sintax, i suggest that you build your regex step by step in order to find out immediately if there's a mistake.

Try using this site for testing regex in real time, it's very good

https://regex101.com/