# MySQL Table name Injection in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-injection

I have necessity to *generate tables* in database in runtime.
I can't use *preparedStatement* in this case.

I tried to find a *library* *to validate* query or tableName input for **MySQL** but found only **ESAPI** which can only *escape* my String. I have my custom validator for It but I know that I can't be sure in this case.

I read up many examples how to abuse SQL Injection. But usually the resources give examples for parameters, not for table name. And as I understand It is possible in case when parameter is in the end of query.

**Question 1**:Could you give an example how to abuse these queries?

```
"CREATE TABLE " + tableName + "(id int primary key)"
```

or

```
"DROP TABLE " + tableName
```

*tableName* - input from a client

It can be very usefull for testing my validator. When I try to do It I have always SQL Syntax error.

**Question 2**: Usually they use the tactic when it's needed to use some character as ,' or something like this and after they write their request. For this tactic it's needed to use spaces.

Is it possible to paste SQL Injection in input which can't have spaces? have only letters? 
Could underscore be as character which interrupt the query?

**UPDATE**:

If It wouuld be safe to add escape-char before underscore in "firstname_lastname" ?

Comment: Not sure but maybe something like `"CREATE TABLE " + "test(id int primary key) ; delete * from user; create table test2 " + "(id int primary key)"`

Comment: [This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) describes the permitted characters in schema object names (like table names). If your validator ensures that your `tableName` follows the rules (preferably for unquoted names) it should be safe.

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables!](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: You can quote the table name like below: "CREATE TABLE \`" + tableName + "\` (id int primary key)".

Comment: @PeterHe That works in many cases — but a clever attacker will input a `tableName` string that includes a back-tick.

Comment: @Donatello, You might like this: [How to filter string for unwanted characters using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4945695/20860)

Comment: @BillKarwin is it not quite good option. Using `tableName.replaceAll()` or `CharMatcher` class it's possible to forget include some char in parameters. Besides I wanted to permit `english_chars_in_lover_case_and_underscores_between_them`. My pattern is `^[a-z]+[[_]*[a-z]+]+[_]*[a-z]+$`. But I can't be sure that It doesn't exist some Injection which can use underscore. At the same time I didn't see any injection without spaces, but I don't have proofs

Comment: I am still having an opportunity to set more severe rules for table naming and maybe I should follow It(exclude underscores). But for next time If I have a choice I think I shouldn't allow to create tables in runtime.

Comment: @BillKarwin Good point. To prevent this, you can escape the back ticks in the tableName by replacing each back-tick with two back-ticks. Then the back-ticks entered by the attacher will become part of the table name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend against doing this, but if you have to, Michael Butscher's comment is pretty good. You can get around spaces by using something like tabs or `%00` `%09` `/**/` `%0d` `%0a` depending on the database implementation.

Comment: Indeed I am eager to permit only lower_cases_english_characters_and_underscores_only_between_them and use simple regex to validate It but I am not experienced in this question